# How to use user data in typo3 flux template without caching it

Tags: caching, typo3, flux, view-helpers, fluid-styled-content

I try to get user session data in a typo3 flux content element. with {user.first_name} I can access the first name of the user, but this will get cached, meaning alls users will see the name of the first one accessing the page. How can I uncache that or load user session data in this template.

**What I already tried**:

- <f:cache.disable> </f:cache.disable> unfortunately the user variable
  are still cached...
- <v:render.uncache> To make the user session data
  accessible in the partial I need to pass it as a parameter, but the
  parameters do get cached :(
- <f:security.ifAuthenticated> does only
  check for permission, but caches aswell.

Working methods:

- adding config.no_cache = 1 or page.config.no_cache = 1 in the typoscript setup works, but I would like to use a solution in flux without typoscript, the USER_INT equival solution should be v:render.uncache, but the argument to be passed is cached as explained above

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `<v:render.uncache>` and fetch the user session data inside the partial.

See https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/issues/1705